# infowindow of the marker hides on hover

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In this project, I have a 2 different kinds of markers which I display on the map using following code.

```
for (i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[i][1], beaches[i][2]),
        map: mapSingle,
        icon: icons[beaches[i][3]].icon
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var content = beaches[i][0];
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseover', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(mapSingle,this);
        };
    })(marker,content,infowindow));
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

Now with new requirement I have to place a new type of marker which can be draggable. So, I have this code

```
com_current = new  google.maps.Marker({
    map: mapSingle,
    draggable: true,
    icon: com_Image,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: {lat: parseFloat('20.5937'), lng: parseFloat('78.9629')},
});
google.maps.event.addListener(com_current, 'mouseover', function() {
    var info = infowindow.getContent();
    infowindow.setContent('show the position of the marker');
    infowindow.open(mapSingle, this);
});
```

Now the problem, I am getting is when I make hover on the this draggable marker, its infowindow gets open which is ok but some of other already open infowindow hides and vice versa. How can I make other already open marker show even if I hover in this draggable marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the same info window object which is used for the non draggable markers. So try with the below code.

```
com_current = new  google.maps.Marker({
    map: mapSingle,
    draggable: true,
    icon: com_Image,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: {lat: parseFloat('20.5937'), lng: parseFloat('78.9629')},
});
infoWindowForDraggableMarker = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
google.maps.event.addListener(com_current, 'mouseover', function() {
    infoWindowForDraggableMarker.setContent('show the position of the marker');
    infoWindowForDraggableMarker.open(mapSingle, this);
});
```

**EDIT**

In the first block of code you are creating info window objects right, change that like below.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
for (i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[i][1], beaches[i][2]),
        map: mapSingle,
        icon: icons[beaches[i][3]].icon
    });
    var content = beaches[i][0];
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseover', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
            return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(mapSingle,this);
        };
    })(marker,content,infowindow));
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

And use the same object for draggable marker also as below.

```
com_current = new  google.maps.Marker({
    map: mapSingle,
    draggable: true,
    icon: com_Image,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: {lat: parseFloat('20.5937'), lng: parseFloat('78.9629')},
});
google.maps.event.addListener(com_current, 'mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.setContent('show the position of the marker');
    infowindow.open(mapSingle, this);
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Naveen. How can i hide other open infowindow if i make hover on  one marker. Can you help

Comment: Just use one info window object. Then there will be only one info window on map.

Comment: that is what I did in my question. But, its not working

Comment: In your question you are creating info window object inside the loop. So there will be more than one info window object. Create one instance like map object .

Comment: thank you I just found out about variable infowindow.